# What can we conclude on the uniform convergence involving the derivative of the functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I meet this problem from a sample test and not sure what conclusion I can get.

Suppose we have a sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$ where $b>a$. We now know that:

$\displaystyle 1.\ \exists x_0\in[a,b], \lim_{n \to\infty}{f_n(x_0)} \  \mathrm{and} \lim_{n \to\infty}{f_n^{'}(x_0)} \ \mathrm{both\ exists}\\
\displaystyle 2.\ {f_n^{''}(x)} \ \mathrm{converges\ uniformly\ on}\ [a,b], \mathrm{\ just \ assume}\ {f_n^{''}(x)\rightrightarrows g(x)}$

Can we get the following:

$\mathrm{I}.\ g(x)\ \mathrm{is\ continuous\ on}\ [a,b]\\
\mathrm{II}.\ f_n^{'}(x) \mathrm{\ converges\ on}\ [a,b]\\
\mathrm{III}.\ f_n(x) \mathrm{\ converges\ pointwisely\ or\ converges\ uniformly\ on}\ [a,b]\\
$

I tried this:

Since ${f_n^{'}(x_0)}$ converges, by Cauchy's convergence criterion, $\forall \varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_1$ such that when $n, m>N_1$, we have $|{f_n^{'}(x_0)}-{f_m^{'}(x_0)}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since ${f_n^{''}(x)\rightrightarrows g(x)}$, $\forall \varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_2$ such that when $n, m>N_2$, $\forall x\in[a,b]$, we have $|{f_n^{''}(x)}-{f_m^{''}(x)}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(b-a)}$. Thus when $n,m>\max(N_1,N_2)$:

$$
f_n^{'}(x)=f_n^{'}(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x}f_n^{''}(t)\ \mathrm{d}t\\ (\mathrm{Is\ this\ step\ right?})\\
f_m^{'}(x)=f_m^{'}(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x}f_m^{''}(t)\ \mathrm{d}t\\
|f_n^{'}(x)-f_m^{'}(x)|\leq|f_n^{'}(x_0)-f_m^{'}(x_0)|+(b-a)\frac{\varepsilon}{2(b-a)}<\varepsilon
$$
(Actually I am not sure if the first two equations above is right, since I do not know whether $f_n^{''}(t)$ is integrable. Now I just assume it is true.)

Then we get $f_n^{'}(x)$ converges uniformly, thus:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x_0}^{x}f_n^{'}(t)\ \mathrm{d}t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(x_0)\right]=\int_{x_0}^{x}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n^{'}(t)\ \mathrm{d}t
$$
Since $f_n^{'}(x)$ converges uniformly and each $f_n^{'}(x)$ is integrable, so is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n^{'}(t)$, and $f_{n}(x_0)$ converges, so is $f_{n}(x)$.

A similar argument can be used to prove $f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly.

Till now I have proven $\mathrm{II}$ and $\mathrm{III}$. I cannot prove $\mathrm{I}$ or give any counterexample. And I'm not sure whether there is mistake in my proof. Thank you for any help!

Edit:

Suggested by Darboux's theorem, I checked this: 
$$
f_{n}(x)\equiv\int_{a}^{x}(t-a)\sin\frac{1}{t-a}\mathrm{d}t
$$
Then 
$$f_{n}^{''}(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{1}{x-a}\cos\frac{1}{x-a}$$
is not continuous. So $\mathrm{I}$ is wrong.

Comment: The answer to I seems to be "false", and a counterexample would be to take all the $f_n$ to be one and the same function $g$ that has two derivatives but whose 2nd derivative is not continuous.

Comment: @murray Could you explain it in more detail? I didn't get it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, should have said: take every $f_{n}$ to be the same function $h$ with $h$, as I propose, to be twice differentiable but with the 2nd derivative $h''$ not continuous. Then all the functions $f_{n}''$ are one and the same function $g = h''$, so certainly the sequence $(f_{n}'')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly, to that $g$. But the uniform limit $g$ is not continuous because it's the 2nd derivative of the function $h$ that does not have a continuous 2nd derivative. (You still must fin a function that is twice differentiable but whose 2nd derivative is discontinuous.)

Comment: @murray Oh I see. I should have noticed this. I check the Darboux's theorem and get some ideas.